# Стриминг видео с веб-камеры

Tags: python, tcp, udp

Пытаюсь реализовать потоковую передачу видео с `веб-камеры`, используя децентрализованную сеть.

Разобрался как передавать картинки (снимки с веб-камеры) на `TCP server`:

**client**

```
import cv2, socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 3333))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read()

status, data = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)

s.send(data)
```

**server**

```
import socket, cv2, numpy as np

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind(('localhost', 3333))
s.listen(5)

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    f = open('1.png', 'wb')

    while 1:
        recv = conn.recv(1024)
        f.write(recv)

       if not recv: break

     f.close()
```

Для передачи видео, я переделал сервер на `UDP`. Возникла проблема, при передачи изображений — `error: message too long`. Узнал, что максимальное количество передаваемых байтов не должно превышать `65535`.

**Данные нужно передавать частями? Как это сделать? Как, собственно, передать видео? Подходит ли для этого библиотека OpenCV?**

Comment: не ясно, что вы фразой  *"децентрализованную сеть."* хотели сказать—у вас один источник (сервер), всё централизировано (для сравнения bittorrent или skype в прошлом  менее централизированы)¶ Посчитайте, сколько байтов требует один кадр в формате png. Сколько кадров в секунду вы хотите, сколько это байт в секунду. Это должно подсказать, что либо видео не нужно либо следует сжимать поток. Чтобы освоиться и понять какая функциональность желательна в вашем случае, попробуйте ffmpeg + ffserver (сравните с [простым примером из гугла](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/))